# android studio on a machine with less than 2GB RAM

Tags: android, performance, ram

My laptop is a bit old...only 1.8GB RAM....Android installs good but when I load a project it freezes with the gradle stuff.

I tried android studion on Windows XP, Ubuntu, tiny core, puppy and now lastly BBQLinux. Each of them have same issue freezing at the gradle stuff...except windows xp which says something like '%1 is not a windows application'!

My question is that can I use swap as RAM, how to enable swap in BBQLinux? Will it make a difference? or is there another alternative?

I don't want to upgrade laptop as I just want to build a simple app for my phone.

Thanks.

Comment: `I don't want to upgrade laptop` Keep it freezing, then.

Comment: If you are still using windows xp, especially as a developing platform, you have bigger issues than just freezes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio takes more memory as well as internet because Android studio is capable of handling all the dependencies automatically (using gradle just like maven in java EE). All tools that does debugging on the real time occupied memory and process cycles. Also the emulator UI quality improved in Android Studio emulator in comparison to Eclipse. So threads and processes takes up huge amount of memory space.
If you still want to lessen the memory issue follow this [link](http://techzog.com/development/android-studio-high-ram-usage/) hope that will help you